# How to fix null subclasses instances with reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, subclass

I have a main instance storing various subclasses instances with options inside.

```
Class MainClass
{
    public bool b;
    public int i;
    public List l = new List();

    Class SubClass1
    {
        ...
    }
    public SubClass1 sub1 = new SubClass1();

    Class SubClass2
    {
        ...
    }
    public SubClass2 sub2 = new SubClass2();
}
```

now, when starting all class are correctly instatiated, then some options are set, and the result is serialized.

The problem arises when (for various reasons) I have to change name of the instances.
E.g. SubClass2---->SubClassB
therefore when de-serializing SubClassB is obviously null.

So I have to fix this drawback and I have tought about reflection.
Something like [pseudocode]

```
foreach(var subclass in MainClass)
{
    if(subclass is null)
    {
        Type subClassType = typeof(subclass);
        subclass = new subClassType();
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

---ADD for completeness the solution from thehennny's hint---

```
private void CheckAndFixNullInstances()
{

    easyRunData.OptionsReport = null;

    Type fieldsType = typeof(EasyRunBinSerializableData);
    FieldInfo[] fields = fieldsType.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

    for (int i = 0; i < fields.Length; i++)
    {
        string str = fields[i].Name + " " + fields[i].GetValue(easyRunData);
        if (fields[i].GetValue(easyRunData) == null)
        {
            string strFieldType = fields[i].FieldType.AssemblyQualifiedName;
            Type t = Type.GetType(strFieldType);
            object item;
            item = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
            fields[i].SetValue(easyRunData, item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please try to explain better what the case.. Do you change the name of the type or of the instance? when\were do you change it? what you get in the foreach of MainClass? anyway, `new subClassType()` is meaningless.. maybe you want `Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(subClass))`

Comment: Sorry for not having been clear enough. The case is that I give the customer the program with MainClass with instances of subclasses: subclass1, subclass2. Then I serialize the Mainclass value.   After (for various reasons) I change the name of a subclass subclass2--->subclassB. Oviously now when deserializing the subclassB is null and I have to take actions.

Comment: Ah...a classic problem of you breaking backwards compatibility, you do realise that you can change the name of the class to whatever you want as long as you serialise it to the same name as you did before. e.g. if you are serialising to XML you can use XML attribute to say what element name your class translates to! https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlrootattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Alas no: using DataContract binary serialization.... ;-( and yes usual longstanding problem of backwards compatibility.

Comment: Right. If you do provide us with a MVP of your code to repro the issue we can go from there, along with a snippet of data which you want deserialised :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with the xml deserialization process, but what you basically want is to loop over all fields of a particular object and fill all null fields with a new object of the fields type.

To get all fields of the type you have to use a [suitable `Type.GetFields` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getfields%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
Then you can loop over the `FieldInfo` objects you got and call the [`FieldInfo.GetValue` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.getvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
After doing the null check you can then create a new object with the [`Activator.CreateInstance` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) by passing the [`FieldInfo.FieldType` Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.fieldtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as parameter and store it in the field using the [`FieldInfo.SetValue` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.setvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: OK I nearly am there!!! I just need to know how to set the new instance. Please see my edit for you.

Comment: You can create a new object with the `Activator.CreateInstance` method i linked in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

The above won't work as you cannot get any type information from a null object.  Essentially when you serialise the object you would want to store the fully qualified name of the class you expect.  Then when you deserialise it out you can read that value.  If the object is "null", you can create an instance of the fully qualified type.

NB: Note "null" in quotes because here "null" is used to semantically mean something which is not there and not necessarily a null object.

NBB: I have solved exactly that problem in a Github project I have which you are welcome to use (https://github.com/ruskindantra/extensions/blob/master/RuskinDantra.Extensions/DataStructures/XmlSerializableInterfaceList.cs).

Comment: Fine that is clear enough. That said it's fair that I can't get info from a null instance but I should be able to iterate on all subclasses of the mainclass indipendently from the fact that its instance is null or not right?

Comment: In your example where is the collection which stores all your subclasses? Essentially yes, if you store them all in a collection you can iterate through it but how will you know that a null Subclass1 needs to be associated to a new SubclassA? Where is that information stored?

Comment: Ok perhaps this is the problem. No colletion only subclass instances. This is why I thought about iterating throgh reflection.

Comment: I believe you are over complicating the problem.  You might want to scope your problem first and then maybe we can offer a solution.  Right now it's quite broad.  You can also provide your class with a custom serialiser/deserializer.  Lots of solutions...what is the problem? :)

Comment: Please see my add. Thanx